# What's wrong with the EQ on this guitar

Tags: audio-recording, equalization

I'm taking a line in from my acoustic guitar. Here it is unaffected:

In my opinion, this sounds terrible. I feel like there's some very offensive frequency somewhere here but when I sweep the EQ I can't find anything that sticks out.

Does any frequency jump out at you that can be eliminated? Or am I hearing something else entirely?

Comment: Possibly 2 things: 1) barred chords sound like your bar finger does not have enough pressure, hence slight buzz, and 2) remote possibility that the 'room tone' is not a good match. For some reason I am having trouble distinguishing if you are playing nylon strings or steel? Which?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like you've recorded it with a piëzo pickup. Which is really quite a horrible choice, always use a condenser microphone if possible!

Comment: Good one leftaroundabout !

Comment: thanks everyone for your comments. @filzilla it's steel strings. not sure what kind of pickup I have but yeah, maybe its piezo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds absolutely normal for an acoustic guitar with a piezo pickup as @leftaroundabout mentioned.

You can get some lovely sounds from a good piezo pickup ([think PRS guitars](http://www.prsguitars.com/p22/)) but cheaper ones can be a bit odd. You tend to get more pick noise and twang with a piezo.

Your best bet is to use a parametric equaliser and just play until you get a sound you like - as this will be different for everyone.

Comment: thanks for the response. It sounds great live so I guess my best bet is to avoid recording from the pickup. thanks!